# Watir - scraping a grid of items

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm trying to scrape the app URLs from a directory that's laid out in a grid:

```
<div id="mas-apps-list-tile-grid" class="mas-app-list">
  <div class="solution-tile-container">
    <div class="solution-tile-content-container">
       <a href="url.com/app/345">
  <div class="solution-tile-container">
    <div class="solution-tile-content-container">
       <a href="url.com/app/567">
... and so on
```

Here are my 2 lines of Watir code that are supposed to create an array with all URLs from a page:

```
company_listings = browser.div(id: 'mas-apps-list-tile-grid')
companies = company_listings.map { |div| div.a.href }
```

But instead of an array with URLs, 'companies' returns:

```
#<Watir::Map: located: false; {:id=>"mas-apps-list-tile-grid", :tag_name=>"div"} --> {:tag_name=>"map"}>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#map` method for a `Watir::Element` (or specifically `Watir::Div` in this case) returns a `Watir::Map` element. This is used for locating `<map>` tags/elements on the page.

In contrast, the `#map` method for a `Watir::ElementCollection` will iterate over each of the matching elements. This is what is missing.

You have a couple of options. If you want all the links in the grid, the most straightforward approach is to create a `#links` or `#as` element collection:

```
company_grid = browser.div(id: 'mas-apps-list-tile-grid')
company_hrefs = company_grid.links.map { |a| a.href }
```

If there are only some links you care about, you'll need to use the link's parents to narrow it down. For example, maybe it's just links located in a "solution-tile-content-container" div:

```
company_grid = browser.div(id: 'mas-apps-list-tile-grid')
company_listings = company_grid.divs(class: 'solution-tile-content-container')
company_hrefs = company_listings.map { |div| div.a.href }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I wasn't familiar with ".links" so appreciate you mentioning it!